# Update fragment content based on tab index in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, tabs

In my application, I have a tab control which has 12 tabs. Each tab has the same fragment but content will be different in each tab. Fragment will have a image control and a TextView. 
How I can assign different fragment content (image and text) based on the tab index. I have all the 12 images and text stored in resource file.

Thanks in advance,
*IamHuM*

Comment: Which tab controller you are using?

Comment: I am using 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout' control inside my activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one fragment with one layout.
And in onCreateView you populate data.

Tips: 
Create fragment with custom method to pass data into.

```
MyFragment.newInstance(imageUrl, title)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (or any Adapter) you can create the new Fragments, and use a constructor to differentiate them. What is great about using a constructor is that you are not limited to setting them up with just an index number:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private static int PAGES = 3;
    private Fragment[] mFragments;


    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mFragments = new Fragment[PAGES];
        mFragments[0] = new MyFragment(0);
        mFragments[1] = new MyFragment(1);
        mFragments[2] = new MyFragment(2);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGES;
    }
}
```

And then your Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private int mData;

    public MyFragment(int data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

My reference: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html